# How to make my Boot.java class as main always on top where i have other processes causing troubles in Java?

Tags: linux, swing, user-interface, java

I have this main.Boot which is actually a splash screen requires to be always on top of everything. But in my case what happening is it gets lost and main.main gets the first position which even do not have any  `setAlwaysOnTop(true);`

How can i set main.Boot always on top?

Boot.java:

```
package main;

public class Boot
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        try {
            String myCmd;      
            // Layer 2 : it can be any other third party Java applications getting launched
            // here its just one example used simple another JWindow...
            myCmd = "java -cp /tmp/dist/AnotherProcess.jar main.main"; 
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCmd);                
            System.out.println("Running: " + myCmd);      
        } catch(Exception e) {   
          System.out.println(e);
        }

        myTimer(); // just a timer counting 40 seconds doing nothing else

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
          }
        });
      }

      private static void createAndShowGUI()
      { 
        window = new JWindow();
        ....
        //setFocusable(true);
        window.pack();
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setSize(screen.width, screen.height+1); 
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
        window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);  // Layer 1 
                                      // (always on top) > but it gets behind
                                      // what ever was launched using .exec(..)
        window.setVisible(true);  
      }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFrame/JWindow doesn's support Modality correctly back to the Native OS this is job for un_decorated `JDialog` with following two methods

- [setAlwaysOnTop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29)
- [setModal(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal%28boolean%29)

Notice not possible (Windows OS) to block keys `Atl + F4` or `Ctlr + Alt + F4`

Comment: OK - is it possible my main.main has `this.setBounds(0,0,screen.width, screen.height);` therefore, this overwrite main.Boot setAlwaysontop method?

Comment: Once i had a problem while suing .setBounds vs setSize when i was trying to resize/scale a jWindow. Since i switched .setBounds to .setSize i was able to do resize/scaling. What i guess maybe that can be the issue. Because when i launch my same application using icon/terminal it works perfect. But its not working in some abnormal situation scenarios.

Comment: YES - indeed the setBounds was bugging in my case. Its solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be supported on your platform.

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29):

> **Note:** some platforms might not support always-on-top windows. To
>   detect if always-on-top windows are supported by the current platform,
>   use `Toolkit.isAlwaysOnTopSupported()` and `isAlwaysOnTopSupported()`. If
>   always-on-top mode isn't supported by the toolkit or for this window,
>   calling this method has no effect.

Comment: Even in another OS such as Windows or Other Linux. It works if i launch the application from Desktop icon. But it does not work when i use it as X windows system.

Comment: I updated my answer. Depending on the JVM version you're using, you may have access to check to see if it's supported in the various modes. You'll need to test in both modes and see if you get something different from `isAlwaysOnTopSupported()` depending on how it's launched. The quote is from the Java 6 docs.

Comment: Alway on top is supported in my platform. I think either its a BUG? Why would it work when i launch it from desktop icon like regular users. But it does not work when i on-boot auto launch it.

Comment: I don't know - if you call `isAlwaysOnTopSupported()` in your code, does it return `true` when launched from the terminal, but `false` when launched the other way?

Comment: Also, is the resulting app (when launched from the terminal) opening up using something other than the XWindows system, vs. when it's opened up in Window Manager? If so, that's probably enough to explain why it's happening. When AWT/Swing couples with the OS windowing toolkit, you might get different results if you're hitting two different windowing toolkits depending on how it's launched.

Comment: TRUE - returned always on system boot, and also when i execute it as normal icon/terminal.